# How to launch an application while holding down a modifier key in Applescript?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to do the equivalent of "Option-click"ing on iTunes icon to get to the "Create Library" option but I'm trying to keep the question and answers **GENERIC to any application** rather than specific to iTunes.

I've tried this code, but it won't even compile

```
tell application "System Events" key down option
tell app iTunes activate
tell application "System Events" key up "option"
```

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/140176?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of the comment URL are:

UI Scripting to launch an app with option key down?

Howdy,

I'm trying to make an automator workflow that will let me switch iPhoto libraries. If you hold the shift and option keys down when launching iPhoto, you can choose to swtich the library. Is it possible using UI scripting in Applescript to launch an app while keystroking option down and shift down?

```
tell app "System Events"
keystroke shift down and option down
tell app "iPhoto" to activate
```

does not work.

Thanks,

Kevin

Hi Kevin
Here is the proper applescript.

```
tell application "System Events"
key down option
key down shift
tell application "iphoto"
activate
tell application "System Events"
key up option
key up shift
end tell
end tell
end tell
```